# How to create sequence based on date i.e 06-11-2020 output field will be 2011001

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Kindly help me to write function or store procedure in SQL server I want to create sequence based on date i.e 06-11-2020 output field will be 2011001.

So far i have written like.

```
  DECLARE @NewLotNo varchar(10);
  DECLARE @PreFix varchar(6);
  DECLARE @Id int;

  SELECT
    @Id = ISNULL(MAX(MeltingId), 0) + 1
  FROM tblMelting

  SELECT
    @PreFix = CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112)

  SELECT
    @NewLotNo = RIGHT(@PreFix, 4) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@Id AS varchar(6)), 6)

  SET NOCOUNT ON

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblMelting (MeltingDt, LotNumber, ItemId, Percentage, GrossWt)
      VALUES (CONVERT(date, @HMeltingDt, 105), @NewLotNo, @HItemId, @HPercentage, @HGrossWt)
  END
```

it works but after 10 number it work like 20110010 it should 2011010

Kindly help me

Regards

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: Seems like instead of `RIGHT('00'...,6)` you want `RIGHT('00'...,3)`. Otherwise this is working exactly as you asked. The last 6 characters of `'0010'` is `'0010'` *not `'010'`.

Comment: Or you simply stop using `RIGHT...` and define a Variable `@CurrYear INT = YEAR(GET_DATE) * 1000` and then use `CAST(@CurrYear + @ID) AS NVARCHAR(10)` or whatever length you need

Comment: Removed irrelevant tags

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'yyMMdd') as date
```